# Excluding query result with in and not in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- Person (BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName)
- Sales (OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate)

I want to list people that made orders both in 2011 and 2014 but never made orders in 2012 and 2013

I would expect this query to work, but it is still listing orders in 2013

```
SELECT 
    s.CustomerID,p.LastName,p.FirstName, s.OrderDate
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader s,Person.Person p
WHERE 
    s.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID 
    AND s.CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                         FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                         WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)
                         GROUP BY CustomerID
                         HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 1)
    AND s.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                             FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                             WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2012, 2013)
                             GROUP BY CustomerID
                             HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 1)
GROUP BY 
    s.CustomerID, p.LastName, p.FirstName, s.OrderDate
```

Results:

```
CustomerID     LastName    FirstName    OrderDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
11001          Young       Amber        2011-06-17 00:00:00.000
11001          Young       Amber        2013-06-18 00:00:00.000
11001          Young       Amber        2014-05-12 00:00:00.000
11017          Clark       Chloe        2011-06-14 00:00:00.000
11017          Clark       Chloe        2013-06-03 00:00:00.000
11017          Clark       Chloe        2014-03-16 00:00:00.000
11018          Mehta       Joe          2011-06-19 00:00:00.000
11018          Mehta       Joe          2013-06-18 00:00:00.000
11018          Mehta       Joe          2014-03-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: You can use https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to format your table

Comment: You said "I want to list people" but your query lists aggregated orders. Understand (and correctly state) your goal **before** you start writing code.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

`having COUNT(CustomerID)>1` mean that you have more that 1 order (2,3,4...).

In the first subquery, use `having COUNT(CustomerID)>0`

and in the second, use:

```
s.CustomerID
not in(select CustomerID from Sales.SalesOrderHeader where YEAR(OrderDate) 
in(2012,2013))
```

without group by and having

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional `COUNT()`

```
  SELECT BussinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
  FROM Person P
  JOIN Sales S
    ON P.BussinessEntityID = S.CustomerID
  GROUP BY BussinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2011,2014)
                             THEN YEAR(OrderDate)
                        END)  = 2
     AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(OrderDate) IN (2012,2013)
                             THEN YEAR(OrderDate)
                        END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, I think you can get the results you want with the EXCEPT keyword as in the following query. I am not able to test it right now though so I might be wrong...

```
SELECT s.CustomerID,p.LastName,p.FirstName, s.OrderDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s,Person.Person p
WHERE s.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID 
AND Year(s.OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)

EXCEPT

SELECT s.CustomerID,p.LastName,p.FirstName, s.OrderDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader s,Person.Person p
WHERE s.CustomerID = p.BusinessEntityID 
AND Year(s.OrderDate) IN (2012, 2013)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this.

```
create table #Person(BussinessEntityID int ,FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100));
create table #Sales(OrderID int ,CustomerID int ,OrderDate datetime);

SELECT s.CustomerID,p.LastName,p.FirstName, s.OrderDate
FROM #Sales s,#Person p
WHERE s.CustomerID = p.BussinessEntityID 
and exists (select top 1 1 from #Sales X Where x.CustomerID=p.BussinessEntityID and Year(x.OrderDate)=2011)
and exists (select top 1 1 from #Sales X Where x.CustomerID=p.BussinessEntityID and Year(x.OrderDate)=2014)
and not exists (select top 1 1 from #Sales X Where x.CustomerID=p.BussinessEntityID and Year(x.OrderDate) in (2012,2013));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of IN and NOT EXISTS.

If I use your example output, for example:

```
--Your sample output
DECLARE @Person TABLE (BusinessEntityID int, FirstName varchar(100), LastName varchar(100))
DECLARE @Sales TABLE (OrderID int IDENTITY(1,1),CustomerID int, OrderDate date)

INSERT INTO @Person VALUES (11001, 'Amber', 'Young'),(11017, 'Chloe', 'Clark')
                          ,(11018, 'Joe', 'Mehta')

INSERT INTO @Sales (CustomerID, OrderDate)
VALUES (11001, '2014-03-26'),(11001, '2013-06-18'),(11001, '2011-06-18')
      ,(11017, '2014-03-16'),(11017, '2013-06-03'),(11017, '2011-06-14')
      ,(11001, '2014-05-12'),(11001, '2013-06-18'),(11001, '2011-06-17')


SELECT DISTINCT S.CustomerID, P.LastName, P.FirstName
  FROM @Sales S INNER JOIN @Person P ON S.CustomerID = P.BusinessEntityID
 WHERE YEAR(S.OrderDate) IN (2011, 2014)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM @Sales S2
                    WHERE S2.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
                      AND YEAR(S.OrderDate) IN (2012, 2013)
                  )
```

Produces output:

```
CustomerID  LastName    FirstName   OrderDate
11001       Young       Amber       2011-06-17
11001       Young       Amber       2011-06-18
11001       Young       Amber       2014-03-26
11001       Young       Amber       2014-05-12
11017       Clark       Chloe       2011-06-14
11017       Clark       Chloe       2014-03-16
```